# How to draw a falling text in JS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am fairly new to using html canvas. I'm creating a breakout game. I want to implement a fall text when a brick is hit that the paddle at the bottom can catch to increase points.

[image: here is what it looks like]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 4;
var brickColumnCount = 4;
var brickWidth = 50;
var brickHeight = 10;
var brickPadding = 15;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var score = 0;
var lives = 3;
var reward = { value: 1, x: canvas.width / 2 - 5, y: 20 };
var bricks = [];
for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}
function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth / 2;
  }
}
function collisionDetection() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if (b.status == 1) {
        if (
          x + 5 > b.x &&
          x - 5 < b.x + brickWidth &&
          y > b.y &&
          y < b.y + brickHeight
        ) {
          reward.value++;
          reward.x = b.x;
          reward.y = b.y;
          // drawReward();
          // drawReward(x, y);
          ctx.font = "16px Arial";
          ctx.fillStyle = "#50b848";
          ctx.fillText("1GB", 8, 10);
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
            document.location.reload();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
function drawBall() {
  // var img = document.getElementById("icon");
  // var img = new Image();
  // img.src = "/images/glo_icon.png";

  // ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 25, 25);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#50b848";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#50b848";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawBricks() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = r * (brickWidth + brickPadding) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = c * (brickHeight + brickPadding) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = `#50b848`;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}
// function drawReward() {
//   // ctx.clearRect(reward.x, reward.y, 30, 30);
//   ctx.font = "25px Arial";
//   ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
//   ctx.fillText(reward.value + "GB", canvas.width / 2 - 5, 20);
//   if (y >= 300) {
//     y = 290; // Set the ball's Y position to the bottom of the canvas
//     dy = 0; //And finally this set the falling is zero
//   }
// }
function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
}
function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
}
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  // drawReward();
  collisionDetection();
  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < -5) {
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (y + dy < -5) {
    dy = -dy;
  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX - 10 && x < paddleX + paddleWidth + 10) {
      dy = -dy;
    } else {
      dy = -dy;
      lives--;
      if (!lives) {
        // alert("GAME OVER");
        // document.location.reload();
      } else {
        x = canvas.width / 2;
        y = canvas.height - 30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
      }
    }
  }
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

when a brick is hit, at text like "2X" should be drawn from that point and drop down to the bottom so the paddle can pick it up.

thanks for the assistance in advance

Comment: This is a fantastic post for a new contributer (welcome to the site)! I can see you've demonstrated your own attempt to solve the problem (in commented-out code); in the future I recommend you emphasize this in your post, since many users will give you flak if they can't immediately see your own attempt at a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to render multiple rewards; this is because several blocks may be hit within a short period of time, leading to several falling text items at once.

The only real trick here is to create an *array* of `rewards`, create another top-level rendering function named `drawRewards` (in the *plural*), and within that function, loop through all rewards in our `rewards` array, and render them. (Oh, and don't forget to actually *add* new rewards into the array whenever a block is hit!) I've modified your code to do all these things; let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 4;
var brickColumnCount = 4;
var brickWidth = 50;
var brickHeight = 10;
var brickPadding = 15;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var score = 0;
var lives = 3;
var reward = { value: 1, x: canvas.width / 2 - 5, y: 20 };
let rewards = [];
var bricks = [];
for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}
function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth / 2;
  }
}
function collisionDetection() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if (b.status == 1) {
        if (
          x + 5 > b.x &&
          x - 5 < b.x + brickWidth &&
          y > b.y &&
          y < b.y + brickHeight
        ) {
          reward.value++;
          reward.x = b.x;
          reward.y = b.y;
          rewards.push({ x: b.x, y: b.y, text: '1GB' });
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
            document.location.reload();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
function drawBall() {
  // var img = document.getElementById("icon");
  // var img = new Image();
  // img.src = "/images/glo_icon.png";

  // ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 25, 25);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#50b848";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#50b848";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawBricks() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = r * (brickWidth + brickPadding) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = c * (brickHeight + brickPadding) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = `#50b848`;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}
function drawRewards() {
  for (let reward of rewards) {
    reward.y = reward.y + 1;
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText(reward.text, reward.x, reward.y);
  }
  
  // Remove any rewards which fall out of view
  rewards = rewards.filter(reward => reward.y < canvas.height);
  
}
function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
}
function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
}
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawRewards();
  drawLives();
  // drawReward();
  collisionDetection();
  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < -5) {
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (y + dy < -5) {
    dy = -dy;
  }
  if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX - 10 && x < paddleX + paddleWidth + 10) {
      dy = -dy;
    } else {
      dy = -dy;
      lives--;
      if (!lives) {
        // alert("GAME OVER");
        // document.location.reload();
      } else {
        x = canvas.width / 2;
        y = canvas.height - 30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
      }
    }
  }
  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```